# For cascading member function calls, why do i need to return the reference? Why isn't just the this pointer sufficient?

Tags: c++, function, reference, cascading, this-pointer

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class armon {
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    armon(int newA, int newB) : a(newA), b(newB) {}

    armon setA(int newA) {
        a = newA;
        return *this;
    }

    armon setB(int newB) {
        b = newB;
        return *this;
    }

    void print(void) { cout << a << endl << b; }
};

int main() {
    armon s(3, 5);

    s.setA(8).setB(9);

    s.print();
}
```

1. Why can't i just return the object with the this pointer to make
   cascaded function calls?
2. Why do i need to return the reference of the object?
3. What would that even do?

Comment: It's better to return `armon&` in `setA` and `setB`.

Comment: because if you don't return the reference and the following call modify the internal state of the class this modifications will no persist in the original object. `Without the reference` you are returning a copy of the object, `with the reference` you are returning the same object.

Answer (score 7):

Returning `this` pointer would be sufficient, too. However, the syntax of cascaded invocation would need to change in the middle of the chain:

```
s.setA(8)->setB(9)->setC(10);
```

This does not look consistent, so returning a reference is a better choice.

Comment: Your code doesn't work either. setA doesn't return a pointer it returns the deference of the this pointer.

Comment: @ArmonSafai My code assumes that the return type has been changed according to your suggestion (i.e. returning `armon*`, with `return this` at the end).